# .NET Globalization Settings - Double values are comma on Windows Server 2012's IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization, regional-settings

I recently moved an asp.net c# website from an old server instance running on Windows Server 2003, to a new box with Windows Server 2012.

Funny enough, the `double` values for GPS coordinates have also changed from being dot notated to comma notated.

I have check both server Regional Settings and set it to South Africa (en-za) - which is where I'm based.

On the new 2012 box with IIS, the values are rendered as follows : **-25,839 28,184**
On the old 2003 box with IIS, the values are rendered as follows : **-25.839 28.184**

Why on earth would it change when I moved it to a new IIS box? Obviously this is breaking quite a few things, as the Map control I use is looking for a dot. Below is an extract from the old server's settings - which is working fine. The new server has been duplicated with the same settings, but no effect was noticed.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Check the globalization settings in machine.config and web.config. IIS uses that to determine locale.

Comment: @Riaandelange: did the marked answer solve your issue? I am having the same problem with the decimal symbol in regional not being applied by IIS on this 2012 server. Another server, with the exact same web config is fine though.

Comment: @callisto Yes, copy the settings to the welcome screen and other accounts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set the regional settings through an RDP Session, you are actually only setting it for your session.

In the Regional Settings Dialog box, click on Administrative tab and copy your new settings to your welcome screen and new Accounts.

Might have to restart the Box, not sure if it is required.

Comment: Brilliant. Just a note to myself - I did not have to restart the box.